# cloudformation template for migrating data from ec2 to rds

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, dms

Hi I am trying to create a cloudformation template to migrate data from postgres in ec2 to rds.I got this template from this link. https://hands-on.cloud/aws-cloudformation-how-to-create-dms-infrastructure-for-relational-db-migration/.

I modified it but i got a error

"Template format error: Every Parameters member must be an object".

In the link he created vpc and security group.i already have vpc and security to configure.
Can u anybod please

```
    Parameters:
             ReplicationInstanceAllocatedStorage:
                 Description: >
        T            he amount of storage (in gigabytes) to be initially allocated
                       for the replication instance.
                 Type: Number
                 Default: 256

             ReplicationInstanceClass:
               Description: >
                The compute and memory capacity of the replication instance as specified
                by the replication instance class.
                Valid Values: dms.t2.micro | dms.t2.small | dms.t2.medium | dms.t2.large |
                dms.c4.large | dms.c4.xlarge | dms.c4.2xlarge | dms.c4.4xlarge
               Type: String
               Default: dms.r5.xlarge

            SrcDbName: postgres
            Type: String

            SrcDbEngine: postgres
            Type: String

            SrcDbServerName: postgres
            Type: String

            SrcDbPort: 5432
            Type: Number

           SrcDbUsername: postgres
           Type: String

           SrcDbPassword: postgres
           Type: String


     Resources:
      ReplicationInstance:
        Type: AWS::DMS::ReplicationInstance
         Properties:
        AllocatedStorage: !Ref ReplicationInstanceAllocatedStorage
        AllowMajorVersionUpgrade: false
        AutoMinorVersionUpgrade: false
        MultiAZ: false
        PubliclyAccessible: false
        ReplicationInstanceClass: !Sub '${ReplicationInstanceClass}'
        ReplicationInstanceIdentifier: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-replication-instance'

    DmsEndpointSource:
    Type: AWS::DMS::Endpoint
    Properties:
        DatabaseName: !Ref SrcDbName
        EndpointType: 'source'
        EngineName: !Ref SrcDbEngine
        ServerName: !Ref SrcDbServerName
        Port: !Ref SrcDbPort
        Username: !Ref SrcDbUsername
        Password: !Ref SrcDbPassword
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of errors in your template.

```
SrcDbName: postgres
  Type: String
```

and all others in that form are not correct. They should be

```
SrcDbName:
  Description: Source Database Name
  Type: String
  Default: postgres
```

for example.

You'll also need your replication destination endpoint and a replication task (IIRC).

Comment: Can we hard code it.Is there a way we could move all the schemas in one template.

Comment: Sure, you can hard code it, but then what's the point of having it as a parameter? Figure out which works best for your deployment situation and work from there.

Comment: Hi thank u for u r resposne.I migrated one schema.is there any way to migrate multiple schemas in one template